# How do I connect upstream outputs as initial state values in Dymos 1.4.1?

Tags: openmdao

I am using Dymos to propagate the dynamics of some ODEs and embed them in a static optimization problem with OpenMDAO. I want to provide the initial value v0 for a state variable v via om.IndepVarComp(). According to the manual this should be possible, when using 'solve segments= forward': "If using solve_segments=forward, one can connect the initial value of a state from an external source."

The 'input_initial' keyword is not available within this old version of Dymos and unfortunately I cannot update it on the computer I am working on so I used the old keyword:
phase.add_state('v', rate_source='EOM.v_dot', units='m/s', **connected_initial=True**)

Using model.connect('v0', 'traj.phase0.states:v') leads to the follwoing error:
Attempted to connect from 'v0' to 'traj.phase0.states:v', but 'traj.phase0.states:v' is an output. All connections must be from an output to an input.

Could someone help me out how to omit this error? I appreciate any help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When using that functionality, connect to `traj.phase0.initial_states:{state_name}`.

Comment: Thank you! One question concerning its dimension. When using the set method the whole state vector is assigned with that value. With using the external connection only the first value is changed. Do I need to work with grid_data.num_nodes or is there an easier way?

Comment: This is sort of a longer discussion that applies when using the `solve_segments` capability:

The entire state vector still exists, but instead of the optimizer figuring out what the values at the nodes should be, the nonlinear solver handles it. 

The resid for that solver wrt `states:x` is such that the first value has to equal `initial_states:x`, and all other values have to be such that they satisfy the defects.  So best practice would be to provide `states:x` with some sort of guess.  This is the intent of the `phase.interp` method, it will apply things to the right number of nodes.